# Designing a Smaller 2000W Transformer PCB to Run 220V Heating Element on 110V

Tags: power, pcb-design, transformer, heat

I'm trying to design a step up transformer that can run my 220V heating element on 110V outlet. I've looked for such transformers through retail, but most of them are bulky and heavy.

Is there a way to design a smaller version of this [bulky transformer](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0026MDI5E), that will be able to provide 2000W of power to my 220V heating element running from 110V outlet?

Comment: 2000W is a large amount of power. Such a device is never going to be small (depending on your reference point for what is big).

Comment: You can use switching technology. It uses several IGBTs to convert low frequency voltage into 10-50 kHz voltage. Then you use high frequency transformer to add the voltage. It gives much more compact designs. However, the switching power supply for 2000 W is not an easy design.

Comment: Depending on the heating element, it may be simpler and cheaper to run 4 of them in parallel...

Comment: 2kW tratsformer weights approx 25kg, not small indeed.

Comment: Alternatively, most houses with 110VAC also have at least 1 220VAC circuit somewhere.   You may be able to have a 220V outlet installed, or maybe there's an outlet close enough for use.  You would need to have a new plug put on the heater, though.  I've never seen an adapter from European 220VAC to American style 220VAC.

Comment: You can try to get an autotransformer, it should be smaller than a regular two-winding transformer. However, the device you linked to may already be an autotransformer (the page does not specify either way).

Comment: @Pentium100 The device weights 11kg, so it is an autotransformer 90%.

Comment: You can't get 2000 watts from a common 15 Amp 120 volt outlet - maximum recommended power is about 1500 watts.  You should install a 240 volt outlet for this heater.

Answer (score 3):

A two thousand Watt transformer is going to be big and heavy. For AC conversion the transformer is a good way to go though. They are efficient and produce real AC waveform outputs.

It is possible to envision a design that would convert the voltage by rectifying the input AC to DC. That would then be converted to a different voltage using a high frequency switcher design and then synthesize a fake AC output. Such device would not be trivial to build however but it could be smaller due to the smaller magnetics required.

Personally I think you would be way better off to set your 220 volt heater aside and get a replacement product that is designed from the outset to work on 110V. And surprisingly that may even cost less.

Comment: Or convert the appliance to 110V. It depends what type of heater it is precisely.